# Loaded SVG paths are not immediately pushed into an array

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to load paths from different SVG files and keep them in an array. I don't really want them in the canvas, since I'm mostly using them to create new paths from them. However, I do want from time to time to actually add them to the canvas to be rendered.

Here's a code snippet that shows my problem:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
});
canvas.renderAll();

var orig_shapes = []; // I want to store the paths here

function loadShape(url){
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(paths, options){
        let shape = paths[0];
        orig_shapes.push(shape);
    });
}

loadShape('path0.svg');
loadShape('path1.svg');

// Add all the loaded shapes to the canvas
console.log(orig_shapes.length);
orig_shapes.forEach(function(shape, index, arr) {
    canvas.add(orig_shapes[index]);
});

canvas.renderAll();
```

This script is loaded at the end of the `<body>` element inside the web page.

I expected to see the paths rendered and a `2` in the console. Unfortunately, all I get is a blue background and a `0`.

Despite this, if I check `orig_shapes.length()` inside the console, I do get a `2` back; so apparently the paths are eventually pushed to the array (but not when I need to). I can even add the paths to the canvas writing `canvas.add(orig_shapes[i])` in the console. They are rendered with no problems.

So what's the problem? Why isn't this working as expected?

Comment: `loadSVGFromURL` is asynchronous

Comment: Thanks! I'm checking out now if using promises can help me to do what I want after the loading is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Durga commented, `loadSVGFromURL` is an asynchronous function, so I needed to check first that the SVGs had been loaded. Here's a version of the script that uses Promises to make sure of this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
});
canvas.renderAll();

var orig_shapes = [];

function loadShape(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fabric.loadSVGFromURL(url, function(paths, options){
            let shape = paths[0];
            orig_shapes.push(shape);
            resolve(shape);
        });
    });
}

function loadShapes(urls, shape_callback) {
    let promises = [];
    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        promises.push(loadShape(url).then(shape_callback));
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function addToCanvas(object) {
    canvas.add(object);
}

loadShapes(['path0.svg', 'path1.svg'])
    .then(function(objs) {
        objs.forEach(addToCanvas);
    });
```

`loadShape` and `loadShapes` both allow me to set especific actions to execute when a single shape is loaded and when all shapes have been loaded, respectively.